# I am trying to alphabetize a combo box using a query in my vb code. How do i get it to work Im having problems?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I want to know if its possible to somehow use a query in my vb code to alphabetize a list in a combo box that I have a dataset connected to?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub ValueSourceAvailabilityBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ValueSourceAvailabilityBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.ValueSourceAvailabilityBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.ValueTrackerDataSet)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'ValueTrackerDataSet3.SA_CountryCode' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.SA_CountryCodeTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ValueTrackerDataSet3.SA_CountryCode)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'ValueTrackerDataSet2.SA_Client' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.SA_ClientTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ValueTrackerDataSet2.SA_Client)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'ValueTrackerDataSet1.Cubes' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.CubesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ValueTrackerDataSet1.Cubes)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'ValueTrackerDataSet.ValueSourceAvailability' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.ValueSourceAvailabilityTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ValueTrackerDataSet.ValueSourceAvailability)

    End Sub

    Private Sub ClientIDComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ClientIDComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged
        SELECT *
FROM dbo.SA_Client 
ORDER by ClientName
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What's your problem, *exactly*? Please, write it on the question body and not on the title

Answer (score 1):

You can't just put a SQL statement inside of a VB .Net sub like that.  You need to either use LINQ/Entity Framework, or format the query as a string and send it to SQL.  The first method would depend on how your entity is set up, while the second method would look something like this:

```
'The SQL Connection
Dim sqlLConn As New SqlConnection() 
'The SQL Command
Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand() 

'Set the Connection String
sqlConn.ConnectionString = "connection string goes here" 
'Open the connection     
sqlConn.Open 
'Set the Connection to use with the SQL Command
sqlCmd.Connection = SQLConn 
' Set your query
sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.SA_Client ORDER by ClientName"  


' DO STUFF WITH THE sqlCmd query here...


'Close the connection
sqlConn.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

First option: You can do it programatically by your sql Query

```
SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY columnName ASC/DESC
```

second option by settiong the Sorted option to TRUE [image]

Answer (score 0):

Would it solve your problem if the data you retrieved from the database already had the data sorted in ClientName order?  In that case, you'll need to change the SQL associated with the Fill method on your `SA_ClientTableAdapter` data adapter.

If you need to sort the data separately from the DataSet and DataTable, you have a couple of options.

1. You can use LINQ, and bind to a sorted version of your data.  Rather than binding directly to the DataSet or DataTable, you'd bind to an expression:

   ```
   [whatever you're binding] = Me.ValueTrackerDataSet2.SA_Client.OrderBy(c=>c.ClientName)
   ```
2. You can use a DataView over the DataTable, which is (one of) the older ways we used to do this:

   ```
   Dim dv as DataView = New DataView(Me.ValueTrackerDataSet2.SA_Client, "", "ClientName", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
   [whatever you're binding] = dv
   ```